# Too many Tasks causes SQL db to timeout

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

My problem is that I'm apparently using too many tasks (threads?) that call a method that queries a SQL Server 2008 database. Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++)
{  
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodThatQueriesDataBase()).ContinueWith(t=>OtherMethod(t));  
}
```

After a while I get a SQL timeout exception. I want keep the actual number of threads low(er) than 100000 to a buffer of say "no more than 10 at a time". I know I can manage my own threads using the ThreadPool, but I want to be able to use the beauty of TPL with the ***ContinueWith***.

I looked at the `Task.Factory.Scheduler.MaximumConcurrencyLevel` but it has no setter.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**
I just tested the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` class (pointed out by Skeet) and still doing the same thing (SQL Timeout).
BTW, this database receives more than 800000 events per day and has never had crashes or timeouts from those. It sounds kinda weird that this will.

Comment: 800,000 events over a 24 time period is a LOT fewer than 100,000 simultaneously.  Even if that was just over 8 hours, it only comes out to 28 queries a second...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) with a limited degree of concurrency, [as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx), then create a [`TaskFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321401.aspx) from that, and use that factory to start the tasks instead of `Task.Factory`.

Comment: I was just reading that article :P. Have you used that same implementation (aka. is it good?). I really don't want to read through the implementation now.

Comment: Bah, Skeeted again (was about to link to that very article)

Comment: Guys, I just tested the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler class and still doing the same thing (SQL Timeout). BTW, this database receives more than 800000 events per day and has never crashed or timeout from those. It sounds kinda weird that this will.

Comment: @Michel: Are you definitely closing your database connections properly? How big is your connection pool compared with the number of tasks you're using?

Comment: @Jon: My connection pool is 20 and I had set the concurrency level to 10. This made me look a bit more into a particular sproc that was a bit slow (~0.5 s). Let's see how it does now. I'll post the progress in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: All good, the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks are not 1:1 with threads - tasks are assigned threads for execution out of a pool of threads, and the pool of threads is normally kept fairly small (number of threads == number of CPU cores) unless a task/thread is blocked waiting for a long-running synchronous result - such as perhaps a synchronous network call or file I/O.

So spinning up 10,000 tasks should not result in the production of 10,000 actual threads.  However, if every one of those tasks immediately dives into a blocking call, then you may wind up with more threads, but it still shouldn't be 10,000.

What may be happening here is you are overwhelming the SQL db with too many requests all at once.  Even if the system only sets up a handful of threads for your thousands of tasks, a handful of threads can still cause a pileup if the destination of the call is single-threaded.  If every task makes a call into the SQL db, and the SQL db interface or the db itself coordinates multithreaded requests through a single thread lock, then all the concurrent calls will pile up waiting for the thread lock to get into the SQL db for execution.  There is no guarantee of which threads will be released to call into the SQL db next, so you could easily end up with one "unlucky" thread that starts waiting for access to the SQL db early but doesn't get into the SQL db call before the blocking wait times out.

It's also possible that the SQL back-end is multithreaded, but limits the number of concurrent operations due to licensing level.  That is, a SQL demo engine only allows 2 concurrent requests but the fully licensed engine supports dozens of concurrent requests.

Either way, you need to do something to reduce your concurrency to more reasonable levels.  Jon Skeet's suggestion of using a TaskScheduler to limit the concurrency sounds like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something wrong with the way you're handling DB connections. Web servers could have thousands of concurrent page requests running all in various stages of SQL activity. I'm betting that attempts to reduce the concurrent task count is really masking a different problem.

Can you profile the SQL connections? Check out perfmon to see how many active connections there are. See if you can grab-use-release connections as quickly as possible.